# Facebook send button: no flyout

Tags: javascript, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use the [send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/) on my current project. I follow the instructions on the page, and now I have the button on the page. It displays nice, I can click on it, but there is no flyout, nothing to see. So after a few searchs, I thought 'hey, might be a style thing'. I set up a new controller with a new layout that loads nothing except the js SDK and the code for the button. Same behaviour. So, here I am, I don't see what I do wrong. Also, no error on the js console or in the 'network' tab.

[The file of interest here](https://gist.github.com/2701361)

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok well, it works and I have no idea why. Probably a cache issue or something, though it's weird because the issue happened on more than one browser.